# How can I slide out a line on the left and right side of text on mouse hover

Tags: html, css, animation

Essentially, I'm looking to animate a line on the left and right side of text that will increase its width to the end of the display when I hover over the text.

Perhaps this will help...

*without hovering:*

```
                  SOME TEXT
```

*on hover:*

----------------------------SOME TEXT--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

I'd like these lines to animate outward to the end on the parent. I've tried using the pseudo elements but had no luck. Some help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How have you tried using pseudo elements? Which ones? Include what you've tried so far.

Comment: Ref: *"I've tried using the pseudo elements but had no luck"* - could you please detail how you tried using pseudo-elements and how does *"luck"* factor in? The coding techniques I know of do not depend on luck.

Comment: You should include your attempt into the question. One should not have to read the comments in order to have all the info to answer. On a different note, have you made any attempt at animating between the two states? Have you researched how it's done? So far it looks like you're simply requesting free work.

Comment: Woah, sorry if I've tickled a nerve there Andrel... I've never asked a question before, so I apologise if I haven't perfectly met your needs.

Comment: They're not ***my needs***. They are community rules. In [so], like in any other community you are supposed to know and respect the rules. Make sure you read [ask] and the answer to [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Welcome to SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it. Feel free to play with animation duration and timing function:

```css
.separator {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.separator:before, .separator:after {
  content: '';
  flex-grow:0;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: currentColor;
  transition: flex-grow .6s cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1);
  margin: 0 .5rem;
}
.separator:hover:before, .separator:hover:after {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="separator">SOME TEXT</div>
<div style="width: 50%; margin-top: 60px;border: 1px solid red; color: blue; padding: 3rem 0;">
  <div class="separator">TEST</div>
```

Comment: Not sure if it matters, but it doesn't work in IE11. No lines on hover.

Comment: Oh well, they'll just have to live without it. Thanks dude.

Comment: @Callum, it should work on IE, but I only have linux here. I'll be able to test it on win from home, in 1.5 ~ 2 hrs from now. Ok, I figured out what might cause it: replace `::after` with `:after` to make it work in IE. (I've just edited it). You also want to run all the CSS through [autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/) before you deploy to production.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a JavaScript solution. Adds `-` to either side until it reaches the end of the line, and it removes the dashes when the mouse moves away.

To prevent the overflow, you just have to track the `clientHeight` and stop adding dashes as soon as the height increases.

```js
var div = document.getElementsByClassName('test')[0];
var origText = div.innerText;
var origHeight = div.clientHeight;
var tooLong = false;
var addTxtInt;

div.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
  addTxtInt = setInterval(function() {
    if (tooLong)
      return;
    if (div.clientHeight > origHeight) {
      div.innerText = div.innerText.substring(1, div.innerText.length - 1);
      tooLong = true;
      return;
    }
    div.innerText = "-" + div.innerText + "-";
    if (div.clientHeight > origHeight) {
      div.innerText = div.innerText.substring(1, div.innerText.length - 1);
      tooLong = true;
      return;
    }

  }, 80);
});

div.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
  clearInterval(addTxtInt);
  div.innerText = origText;
  tooLong = false;
});
```

```css
.test {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class='test'>SOME TEXT</div>
```